# from GPT to MBR and vice versa, now I do not see previous partitions

Tags: multi-boot, mbr, gpt, boot-partition

I will go straight to the point,

I have a laptop in dual boot (Windows 10 and Kali Linux) which has been converted from the GPT partition to the MBR (for reasons I do not know), I used *gdisk* to reconvert the partition table to the original GPT but now the system at startup does not recognize any operating system, I can only enter the bios.

I do not have a windows cd or a live linux, what could be the problem and how can I solve it?

EFI System info:

[image: photo]

Partition print:

[image: photo]

edit: I found an ubuntu live cd if that can help

Comment: please include the image here. No one will click on those links

Comment: @phuclv: new users cannot add images

Comment: @grawity I know. But they can add images to stack.imgur and then we'll fix the link for them

Answer (score 0):

UEFI boot entries usually refer to a specific partition GUID (shown in *gdisk* as "partition unique GUID"). Converting to MBR resulted in the old partition-GUIDs being lost (as MBR has nowhere to store them) and the subsequent conversion to GPT had to assign new GUIDs.

You can either update the boot entries according to the new GUID, or change the partition's actual GUID to match what was previously stored in the boot entry.

To do the latter:

1. Run `efibootmgr -v` and copy the GUID shown in `HD(1,GPT,…)` identifiers.
2. In *gdisk*, use <kbd>x</kbd> to enter the "expert mode" menu.
3. In the expert mode menu, use <kbd>c</kbd> to change the GUID of your 4th partition.
4. Examine, save and exit.

---

Note that each partition has two GUIDs for different purposes, somewhat confusingly named in *gdisk*:

- "Partition unique GUID" – this is different for every partition, and stored in EFI boot entries. This is the one you need to change.
- "Partition GUID code" – this is generic and only describes the *type*, so for EFI system partitions it's always the same.